# Why Angular Material variables doesn't work with colors from a palette?

Tags: sass, angular-material

I want to set a background color of the mat-card. To do that I'm using Angular Material variable (or whatever that is), like this:

```
.mat-mdc-card {
  --mdc-elevated-card-container-color:  mat.get-color-from-palette($my-custom-primary, 900);
}
```

This doesn't work at all and there's still a default color.

But when I do that it works:

```
.mat-mdc-card {
  --mdc-elevated-card-container-color: #212121;
}
```

Can someone explain to me how to be able to use a color from the palette with these strange Angular Material "variables"?

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
$dark-primary: mat.get-color-from-palette($my-custom-primary, 900);

.mat-mdc-card {
  --mdc-elevated-card-container-color: #{$dark-primary};
}
```